# How can I assign my login Id to a member to show classes they have book in for?

Tags: c#, sqlite, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm currently stuck on trying to assign my login Id to a member in .net core.
I'm currently using SQLite for development. I have a user model (that is used when logging in) and then a member model (used to store the information on that user). I'm hoping to assign the login to the member, so when the member books into a class that they can view which classes they have booked into. however, I'm having an issue assigning the login id to the member.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code below is my user model.

```
    public enum Role { Admin, Manager, Guest }

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The code below is my member model.

```
public enum Belt { White, Yellow, Green , Purple, Orange, Blue, Brown, Red, Black}
    public class Member
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]

        public User UserId { get; set; }

        //removed other details as too long

    }
```

My login method within the login controller is:

```
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([Bind("Username,Password")] User m)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(m);
            }

            var user = _svc.Authenticate(m.Username, m.Password);
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "Invalid Login Credentials");
                ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "Invalid Login Credentials");
                return View(m);
            }

            var principal = BuildPrincipal(user);
            // check user can login
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                principal
            );

            return Redirect("/");

        }
```

Sorry if this question has been asked already or this hasn't been asked in an appropriate manner, I'm still a beginneer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cookie authentication using `HttpContext.SignInAsync` , you could always get the login user's claims from Http Context in controller like :

`User.Claims.Where(x=>x.Type==ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).FirstOrDefault().Value`

The claims are from `BuildPrincipal` where you put the claims in . You can then get the claims and set to Member or User properties .